# Dropdownlist box in asp.mvc 2 and jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I am looking for a code sample to create a dropdownlistbox with jquery? Looking to make an Ajax call and pass on the selected value to the controller ?